# PHP conversion to unix timestamp gives -2hr

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Today I've hit a problem with PHP. Conversion of DateTime to Unix timestamp worked as expected until now. I'm using this code to convert time:

```
<?php
$date = date_create("08:00");
$unix = $date->getTimestamp();
echo $unix;
?>
```

And echoed text is 1463119200 which points to time 06:00, according to online converter. Any time given as string to date variable results in time - 2 hours. Why it is doing such a thing? And why everything worked until now ? Thanks for your responses in advance.

Comment: What is the timezone setting in your php.ini?

Comment: date.timezone = Europe/Paris

Comment: And Paris is currently 2 hours difference from UST/UTC

Comment: If was working and now not, maybe you change the timezone in your server or in the php scripts.

Comment: So what code I'm supposed to use to properly convert time from string to unix timestamp ? and how could it worked all right until now ? BTW When you say Paris is CURRENTLY 2 hours difference from UTC, it means that only now (when is summer time) is 2 hours difference and during winter time there is only 1 hour difference ?

Comment: I haven't change timezone in server neither in scripts. That's is why I'm confused about it.

Comment: A Unix timetamp is always UTC; why do you need a timestamp anyway? Why can't you use the DateTime object? What do you want to display?

Comment: I'm using timestamp to simplify many time calculations further in code. I'm new in PHP and I've tried to use DateTime object but I had many troubles with it so i tought that convert all datetime to unix would be great to simplify calculations. And it was until now

Comment: DateTime objects are a lot easier to use than unix timestamps, because they implicitly include the timezone rather than relying on server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Online converters tend to use UST/UTC by default. Since the unix epoch is a specific point in time (with no timezone data) your timestamp is a count of the number of second since then.

When you ask the online converter to put it back into a human readable time it gives the correct time but in its own timezone.